# If M.2 share bandwidth with my SATA, does that make it slow as SATA?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata, m.2

I'm new to this whole PC building thing and while shopping for a motherboard, I've found that the M.2 slot, if used, will disable a SATA port (or 2). After further research, I've found that it might be because they share the same bandwidth.

Does that mean that the M.2 port will be limited to the same 6GB/s speed limit of SATA ports? Can anyone clarify my mind about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've found that the M.2 slot, if used, will disable a SATA port (or 2).

Wikipedia suggests the following:

> Computer bus interfaces provided through the M.2 connector are PCI Express 3.0 (up to four lanes), Serial ATA 3.0, and USB 3.0 (a single logical port for each of the latter two).

If your M.2 connector disables a SATA 3 port it means the maximum speeds it can reach is that of what SATA 3 can provide.  This means if a identical SSD product were to exist in both a 3.5"/2.5" form factor and a M.2 form factor they would perform identically.

> Does that mean that the M.2 port will be limited to the same 6GB/s speed limit of SATA ports?

Yes, it means exactly that.

[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2)

Comment: There is the possibility that an M.2 slot shares lanes with a SATA expander chip and if the M.2 is populated then it disables the SATA chip and so disables its ports. This could mean that the M.2 is faster than SATA as it is using full PCIe rather than a SATA connection. It's difficult to say with certainty that it is a SATA connection going to the M.2. I'd say you are *probably* right, as diverting the SATA lanes is the easiest way to set up electronically, but there is a faint *possibility* of doing it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread but I have wondered about this and haven't found a clear answer so it was time to do some experiments.

Motherboard: Asus Prime Z590-A with Intel i5-11600K + 16GB memory.

SSD in M.2 slot 1: WD_Black SN850 1TB (PCIe 4.0)

SSD in M.2 slot 3: WD 970 EVO 250GB (PCIe 3.0)

Hard disks installed in SATA ports 1-3

(The manual says: "M.2_3 shares bandwidth with SATAG_6. When M.2_3 runs SATA mode, SATA6G will be disabled.")

CrystalDiskMark results with both NVMe SSDs installed but no drives in SATA ports 4-6

WD_Black SN850 - 6907.83MB/s read, 5248.49MB/s write

WD 970 EVO - 3504.43MB/s read, 1543.56MB/s write

Hard disks working and benchmarking as expected.

I then installed hard disks in SATA ports 4, 5 & 6:

Original drives working and benchmarking as before, new drives working and benchmarking as expected.

Therefore, in the case of this configuration at least, there is no sharing as the SSDs in the M.2 ports are NVMe and the hard disks are SATA so they are accessed in different ways. Had I used SATA SSDs in the M.2 slots they would have had to share with the SATA ports on the motherboard. This may not be the case with all motherboards, it depends on the wording which hasn't been clear in the boards I've looked at.

I hope that clears it up? In short, this motherboard lets me use all 3 M.2 slots (with NVMe SSDs) as well as all 6 SATA ports. Yay! :)